# Recursively get a value of a deque with an index

Tags: java

I am building a circular sentinel deque and I am want to get an value without altering the list.

```
public class LinkedListDeque<Generic> {
    private GenericNode sentinel;
    private int size;
    private class GenericNode{
        public Generic item;
        public GenericNode next;
        public GenericNode prev;

    public GenericNode(GenericNode p, Generic i, GenericNode n) {
        item = i;
        next = n;
        prev = p;
     }
    }

    public LinkedListDeque() {
        sentinel = new GenericNode(null, null, null);
        sentinel.next = sentinel;
        sentinel.prev = sentinel;
        size = 0;
    }
    public LinkedListDeque(Generic x) {
        sentinel = new GenericNode(null, null, null);
        sentinel.next = new GenericNode(sentinel, x, sentinel);
        sentinel.prev = sentinel.next;
        size = 1;
public Generic getRecursive(int r) {
        if (r == 0) {
            return sentinel.next.item;
        } else {
            sentinel.next = sentinel.next.next;
            return getRecursive(r-1); //fix this
        }
    }
```

This method works but it also alters my list which I do not want. When I try

```
this.next.getRecursive(r-1)
```

it throws an error. I do not know how to reference it as the sentinel seems to be throwing me off.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to modify the state, then you need to pass a reference node along, for example:

```
public Generic getRecursive(int r) {
    return getRecursive(r, sentinel);
}

private static Generic getRecursive(int r, GenericNode node) {
    if (r == 0) {
        return node.item;
    }
    return getRecursive(r - 1, node.next);
}
```